how to mocking dbcontext for return value?
I'm writing a test for a method for getting an account by ID from a database and I'm faced with the problem of simulating a database context. Can I mock the DbContext this way and get the expected account entry value from it?
method under test:
public async Task<Account> GetAccountById(int id)
{
    var account = await _cacheService.GetAsync<Account>(GetAccountByIdCacheKey(id));
    if (account is not null) return account;

    using var ctx = factory.CreateDbContext();
    account = await ctx.Accounts.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id).ConfigureAwait(false);
    RegistrationException.ThrowIfNull(account);
    await AddAccountToCache(account).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return account;
}

here is my test code:
[Fact]
public async Task GetAccountById_ShouldReturnCorrectAccount_FromDataBase()
{
    // Arrange
    var accountId = 1;
    var expected = new Account { Id = accountId, Login = "test", CreationTime = DateTime.Now };                       
    
    var mockCacheService = new Mock<ICacheService>();
    mockCacheService.Setup(service => service.GetAsync<Account?>(It.IsAny<string>()))
                    .ReturnsAsync((Account?)null);

    var mockCacheServiceFactory = new Mock<ICacheServiceFactory>();
    mockCacheServiceFactory.Setup(factory => factory.GetCacheService(It.IsAny<string>()))
                           .Returns(mockCacheService.Object);                        

    var mockDbContext = new Mock<RegistrationDataContext>();
    mockDbContext.Setup(context => context.Accounts.Add(It.IsAny<Account>()))
                .Returns(expected);

    var mockDbContextFactory = new Mock<IDbContextFactory<RegistrationDataContext>>();
    mockDbContextFactory.Setup(factory => factory.CreateDbContext())
                        .Returns(mockDbContext.Object)
                        .Verifiable(Times.Once);

    var sut = new AccountService(mockDbContextFactory.Object, mockCacheServiceFactory.Object, Mock.Of<IKernelRegionAccountService>());

    // Act
    var actual = await sut.GetAccountById(accountId);

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(expected.Id, actual.Id);
    Assert.Equal(expected.Login, actual.Login);
    Assert.Equal(expected.CreationTime, actual.CreationTime);
}


There is usually no need to mock entity framework contexts, you can simply mock your AccountService.GetByAccountId to directly return the necessary data, skipping the DbContext mock which is redundant.
